What does it mean: " Don’t shop-order. "
On a caregiver forum, people are talking about their experiences and how to make life easier when they give caregiving to the elderly. One of those advices is like this:
Don’t shop-order.
Amazon lets you return anything for any reason. Aging Care
I looked "shop order" up and it seems to mean "the orders you place to produce materials you manufacture in your plant.".
The meaning doesn't sit well. Why would you as a caregiver get involved in the manufacturing processes. I just didn't understand it.
What does it mean?

It's clearly meant to be a dash, not a hyphen. The poster should have inserted spaces. "Don't go to the shops - order things online."

That makes sense, @KateBunting. I didn't think of it, and was puzzling over the meaning

@KateBunting, I would never imagine that. Thank you. However, the second part could act as a seperate sentence. "Don't shop. Order." so why put the second sentence in a dash?

Because the two pieces of advice are part of the same idea. "Order online instead of shopping in person."

@KateBunting, That was very clear thanks.

You're reading it incorrectly. It isn't a hyphenated word "shop-order". The hyphen is meant to be a dash (—), also called the em dash. It is longer than a hyphen (-).
The dash is a pause that separates a main clause from a separate statement or some parenthetical information. So your example means don't shop; order instead.
Many English keyboards do not have a dash symbol on them. But, when using a word processor like Word or Google Docs, inserting a space, then a hyphen, then another space, will change into a dash. Because sites like this one use a plain text editor with markup, that does not happen. Perhaps that's why the site you were reading has a hyphen where a dash should be?

Yes. Double-check that Google Docs converts to em dash. Word converts to en dash as you describe, and em dash after "character hyphen hyphen character space" series.
